# Wildcard '_' in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, logparser

I am trying to replicate a table in my Oracle SQL database. Looking at the code used to generate the table from LogParser, I noticed that there was this statement in it:

```
SELECT '_' AS EONE, '_' AS ETWO, '_' AS ETHREE FROM iislog TO TABLE
```

I get that the underscore is a wildcard for any string, but I'm confused as to where it get's a value from and why it can be used for any data type. I don't know if it pulls existing data from the table, or if it's used to pull arguments passed in from LogParser.

Comment: Those underscores are nothing but underscores here. (They can be used as wildcards in LIKE/REGEXP.)

Comment: It's only a wildcard when used with `LIKE`

Comment: Your query should work, and return rows with 3 columns having content `'_'`

Comment: Yup, that query generates a result set composed of three string fields, and thus it uploads a records with three strings.